# How to hide keyboard just by one tap outside of an edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

I want to hide the keyboard by tapping outside of edittext. This is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:onClick="rl_main_onClick">
<RelativeLayout
  //Here there are some widgets including some edittext.
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my java code (MainActivity):

```
public void rl_main_onClick(View view) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

But I have to tap twice to hide keyboard. The first tap just changes "next" (for last edittext it's "done") to "enter" icon, then the second tap hides the keyboard.
This is what that happen by the first tap:

[image: What the first tap does.]

Now I have two questions:

1. How can I fix it and hide keyboard by just one tap?
2. Is it possible to do it for all of my edittext (one code for all)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to replace `onClick` with `onTouch`. For this you need to change your layout attributes like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <RelativeLayout>

        // widgets here

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then remove `rl_main_onClick(View view) {...}` method and insert `onTouch` listener method inside of `onCreate()` :

```
findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use below Process. It's Working For Me Perfectly. Add below function in your activity Class.

```
  override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    val v = currentFocus
    if (v is EditText) {
        val outRect = Rect()
        v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
        if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
            Log.d("focus", "touchevent")
            v.clearFocus()
            val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.windowToken, 0)
        }
    }
}
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)}
```

You can check Focus status using Below Code. Both activity and Fragment

```
appCompatEditText.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            if (!hasFocus) {
                toast("Focus Off")
            }else {
                toast("Focus On")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin version with extension

```
fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = context!!.getSystemService(android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as? InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.windowToken, 0)
}
```

And call it like this from fragment

```
view.setOnClickListener {
    it.hideKeyboard()
}
```

Or like this from activity, contentView is the id of my root view

```
val contentView: View = findViewById(R.id.contentView)
    contentView.setOnClickListener {
    it.hideKeyboard()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating through all the views or overriding dispatchTouchEvent.

Why Not just override the onUserInteraction() of the Activity this will make sure keyboard dismisses whenever the user taps outside of Editext.

Will work even when edit text is inside the scrollView.

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    super.onUserInteraction()
}
```

Comment: @SKG You just forget to call super. Otherwise, no Interaction will work. 
super.onUserInteraction()

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will help, I did something like that but for **fragments**. They are inside containers(FrameLayouts) in activity_main xml.

First I add this to the parent fragment layout:

```
android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Then I declare and initialize the layout:

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
```

And in onCreateView:

```
constraintLayout = ppm.findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);
constraintLayout.setOnFocusChangeListener(onFocusChangeListener);
```

And here is the onFocusChangeListener:

```
View.OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if (hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
override fun onUserInteraction() {
    if (currentFocus != null) {
        val imm: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
```

This works, but when I press the keyboard to type it is also hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly working and clean solution:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    currentFocus?.let {
        val imm: InputMethodManager = getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE
        ) as (InputMethodManager)
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(it.windowToken, 0)
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attributes to the top layout of the layout file to clear the focus by tapping the outside of the TextField.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

For Fragment.
Add the following code to OnFocusChangeListener to hide the keyboard by tapping the outside of the TextField.
I will define it in InterFace and implement it in a concrete class.

```
public interface CommonFragment {

    FragmentActivity fragmentActivity();

    default View.OnFocusChangeListener hideKeyboardListener() {
        return (view, b) -> {
            if (b) {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) fragmentActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        };
    }
}

public MyFragment extends Fragment implements CommonFragment {

    @Override
    public FragmentActivity fragmentActivity() {
        return requireActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // "binding.container" is top layout by View Biding 
        binding.container.setOnFocusChangeListener(hideKeyboardListener());
    }
}
```