# Hide keyboard when tap outsite of an edittext with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to hide the keyboard, I thought I had found a solution in this post

[How to hide keyboard just by one tap outside of an edittext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452321/how-to-hide-keyboard-just-by-one-tap-outside-of-an-edittext/40453206)

The solutions works! but I have a recyclerview and it stays blocked when the keyboard hides

thanks in advance

Comment: almost always works, sometimes the app stops :/

Comment: I just checked, the app was stopping because of an error of mine, I solved it, but does not work yet the hide keyboard..... No, I havent, I am trying only with recyclerview

Comment: I tried with another activity, look, in the layout I put a EditText, and I set a name to its LinearLayout and this id I called in the code in the class instead of the recyclerview id, and Yes!, works! but with the recyclerview that I need does not work :/

Comment: you should add click listener on the `recyclerView` item.